# Problem with wrapfigure repeating in the next section

Tags: wrapfigure

I have a problem with wrapfigure. I only want to wrap the picture in the first section, but it automatically repeats in the second section. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\section*{Lebenslauf}
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{3cm}
   
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{foto.jpeg}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\subsection*{Heading}

Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 

\subsection*{Heading}

Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really want the section title to be also indented?

Comment: yes I would prefer it this way, if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not happen if there is some text before the wrapfigure environment.  As there was none, I added a `\leavevmode`, and to ensure the alignment of the top of the image with the section title, I used `\raisebox{0pt}` with the optional argument for the height of the box to fool latex, and make it believe the image is higher than it is really.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode
\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{l}{3cm}
\raisebox{0pt}[\height+\baselineskip]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{foto.jpeg}}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection*{Heading}

Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text

\subsection*{Next Heading}

Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\section*{Lebenslauf}

\subsection*{Heading 1}
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{l}{3cm} 
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}     
    \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3cm]{example-image-A}
\end{wrapfigure} 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 


\subsection*{Heading 2}

Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text 
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
\end{document}
```

[image: xxy]